# "Ghost" kubernetes pod stuck in terminating

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

## The situation

I have a kubernetes pod stuck in "Terminating" state that resists pod deletions

```
NAME                             READY STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
...
funny-turtle-myservice-xxx-yyy   1/1   Terminating  1          11d
...
```

Where `funny-turtle` is the name of the helm release that have since been deleted.

## What I have tried

#### try to delete the pod.

Output: `pod "funny-turtle-myservice-xxx-yyy" deleted`

Outcome: it still shows up in the same state.
   - also tried with `--force --grace-period=0`, same outcome with extra warning

> warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.

#### try to read the logs (kubectl logs ...).

Outcome: `Error from server (NotFound): nodes "ip-xxx.yyy.compute.internal" not found`

#### try to delete the kubernetes deployment.

but it does not exist.

So I assume this pod somehow got "disconnected" from the aws API, reasoning from the error message that `kubectl logs` printed.

I'll take any suggestions or guidance to explain what happened here and how I can get rid of it.

#### EDIT 1

Tried to see if the "ghost" node was still there (`kubectl delete node ip-xxx.yyy.compute.internal`) but it does not exist.

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski `kubectl get nodes | grep ip-xxx.yyy.compute.internal` empty results. But in the nodelist there are several other ips with the same format (varying xxxs and yyys)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try removing the finalizers from the pod:

```
kubectl patch pod funny-turtle-myservice-xxx-yyy -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

Comment: It works! Do you know what could have put this pod in this state?

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks, this saved my life. PS: there's a typo in your command, the closing ' is missing.

Comment: Is there a way to know if finalizers were actually causing the problem?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the solution proposed by the accepted answer did not work, it kept stuck in "Terminating" status. What did the trick for me was:

```
kubectl delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force
```

Comment: This does not actually delete the pod. It only deletes the reference to the container and the container may continue to run forever

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions did not work in my case, except I didn't try restarting all the nodes.

The error state for my pod was as follows (extra lines omitted):

```
$ kubectl -n myns describe pod/mypod  
Status:                    Terminating (lasts 41h)  
Containers:  
  runner:  
    State:          Waiting  
      Reason:       ContainerCreating  
    Last State:     Terminated  
      Reason:       ContainerStatusUnknown  
      Message:      The container could not be located when the pod was deleted.
                    The container used to be Running  
      Exit Code:    137  

$ kubectl -n myns get pod/mypod -o json  
    "metadata": {
        "deletionGracePeriodSeconds": 0,  
        "deletionTimestamp": "2022-06-07T22:17:20Z",  
        "finalizers": [  
            "actions.summerwind.dev/runner-pod"  
        ],
```

I removed the entry under finalizers (leaving finalizers as empty array) and then the pod was finally gone.

```
$ kubectl -n myns edit pod/mypod
pod/mypod edited
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was having the same issue also with that runner haha you saved me

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing worked, no logs, no delete, absolutely nothing. I had to restart all the nodes, then the situation cleared up, no more Terminating pods.

Comment: You might want to try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954174/kubernetes-namespaces-stuck-in-terminating-status/60328565#60328565