# How to force delete a Kubernetes Namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-namespace

How do I force delete Namespaces stuck in Terminating?

### Steps to recreate:

1. Apply this YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: delete-me
spec:
  finalizers:
    - foregroundDeletion
```

2. `kubectl delete ns delete-me`
3. It is not possible to delete `delete-me`.

The only workaround I've found is to destroy and recreate the entire cluster.

### Things I've tried:

None of these work or modify the Namespace. After any of these the problematic finalizer still exists.

#### Edit the YAML and `kubectl apply`

Apply:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: delete-me
spec:
  finalizers:
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f tmp.yaml 

namespace/delete-me configured
```

The command finishes with no error, but the Namespace is not udpated.

The below YAML has the same result:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: delete-me
spec:
```

#### `kubectl edit`

`kubectl edit ns delete-me`, and remove the finalizer. Ditto removing the list entirely. Ditto removing `spec`. Ditto replacing `finalizers` with an empty list.

```
$ kubectl edit ns delete-me 

namespace/delete-me edited
```

This shows no error message but does not update the Namespace. `kubectl edit`ing the object again shows the finalizer still there.

#### `kubectl proxy &`

- `kubectl proxy &`
- `curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/yaml" -X PUT --data-binary @tmp.yaml http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/delete-me/finalize`

As above, this exits successfully but does nothing.

#### Force Delete

`kubectl delete ns delete-me --force --grace-period=0`

This actually results in an error:

```
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
Error from server (Conflict): Operation cannot be fulfilled on namespaces "delete-me": The system is ensuring all content is removed from this namespace.  Upon completion, this namespace will automatically be purged by the system.
```

However, it doesn't actually do anything.

#### Wait a long time

In the test cluster I set up to debug this issue, I've been waiting over a week. Even if the Namespace might eventually decide to be deleted, I need it to be deleted faster than a week.

#### Make sure the Namespace is empty

The Namespace is empty.

```
$ kubectl get -n delete-me all

No resources found.
```

#### `etcdctl`

```
$ etcdctl --endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:8001 rm /namespaces/delete-me

Error:  0:  () [0]
```

I'm pretty sure that's an error, but I have no idea how to interpret that. It also doesn't work. Also tried with `--dir` and `-r`.

#### `ctron/kill-kube-ns`

There is a [script for force deleting Namespaces](https://github.com/ctron/kill-kube-ns). This also does not work.

```
$ ./kill-kube-ns delete-me

Killed namespace: delete-me

$ kubectl get ns delete-me 

NAME        STATUS        AGE
delete-me   Terminating   1h
```

#### `POST`ing the edited resource to /finalize

[Returns a 405](https://gist.github.com/willbeason/be90dac4c9d1b2a26b8c0a10ac1e50dc). I'm not sure if this is the canonical way to POST to /finalize though.

### Links

[This](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19317)
[appears](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73186)
[to](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60807)
[be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369247/namespace-stucked-as-terminating-how-i-removed-it)
[a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954174/kubernetes-namespaces-stuck-in-terminating-status)
[recurring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.1/troubleshoot/ns_terminating.html)
[problem](https://nasermirzaei89.net/2019/01/27/delete-namespace-stuck-at-terminating-state/)
[and](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/)
[none](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1540779)
[of](https://linuxhelp4u.blogspot.com/2019/01/kubernetes-remove-namespace-stuck-in.html)
[these](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1541350)
[resources](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37554)
[helped](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/).

[Kubernetes bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77086)

Comment: You're doing it correct, but there's something that takes a long time to delete inside. There's no way to force it more. Just check what's left `kubectl -n <ns> get all -o yaml` maybe it gives you some more info.

Comment: Have you tried removing it from etcd? LIke etcdctl rm /namespaces/delete-me ?

Comment: @MaxLobur The Namespaces are empty, and in some cases I've been waiting longer than a week for deletion. Updated post.

Comment: I have got this issue for any namespace I create: `microk8s v1.26.0 on Ubuntu 22.04`. The answers work, but it would be nice to know (+ fix) the actual root cause.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `kubectl proxy` try is almost correct, but not quite. It's possible using JSON instead of YAML does the trick, but I'm not certain.

The JSON with an empty finalizers list:

```
~$ cat ns.json

{
  "kind": "Namespace",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "delete-me"
  },
  "spec": {
    "finalizers": []
  }
}
```

Use `curl` to `PUT` the object without the problematic finalizer.

```
~$ curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @ns.json http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/v1/namespaces/delete-me/finalize

{
  "kind": "Namespace",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "delete-me",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/delete-me/finalize",
    "uid": "0df02f91-6782-11e9-8beb-42010a800137",
    "resourceVersion": "39047",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-04-25T17:46:28Z",
    "deletionTimestamp": "2019-04-25T17:46:31Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Namespace\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"delete-me\"},\"spec\":{\"finalizers\":[\"foregroundDeletion\"]}}\n"
    }
  },
  "spec": {

  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Terminating"
  }
}
```

The Namespace is deleted!

```
~$ kubectl get ns delete-me

Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "delete-me" not found
```

Comment: Small error in the json. `"name": "delete-me" ` should not have a comma at the end.

Answer (score 38):

I loved this answer extracted from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77086#issuecomment-569663112)

In one terminal:

```
kubectl proxy
```

In another terminal:

```
kubectl get ns delete-me -o json | \
  jq '.spec.finalizers=[]' | \
  curl -X PUT http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/delete-me/finalize -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @-
```

Comment: My server refuses the connection no matter what I try. My server version is 1.16 and my client is 1.19.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer is correct.

Answer (score 22):

Applying this command after replacing the two occurrences of `<NAME_OF_NAMESPACE>` with the actual name of the namespace in Termination can solve the issue:

```
kubectl get ns <NAME_OF_NAMESPACE> -o json | jq '.spec.finalizers = []' | kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/<NAME_OF_NAMESPACE>/finalize" -f -
```

##### Explanation:

Most replies seem to do the same thing here; remove the finalizers from the namespace. In this case, this is done in three steps:

1. `kubectl get ns <NAME_OF_NAMESPACE> -o json` returns the namespace configuration in json format. This is piped into the next command:
2. `jq '.spec.finalizers = []'` removes all finalizers from the json configuration. The resulting json (without finalizers) is then piped into the next command:
3. `kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/<NAME_OF_NAMESPACE>/finalize" -f -`, injects the updated json namespace configuration (without finalizers) into k8s.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. You should always give a little explanation to your code.

Comment: While this all works perfectly well with this workaround, I wonder why it happens in the first instance. For me, this workaround is required whenever I `kubectl create ns <something>` and then try to delete it a few minutes after, without modifying it in any way, or without creating elements.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a modification to the command provided by the user *Ushakov Roman* (detailed explanation see there). Compared to Ushakov Roman's solution, defining the `namespace` variable in the beginning helps to reduce the number of places where the namespace name actually has to be typed:

```
namespace=<NAME_OF_NAMESPACE> && kubectl get ns $namespace  -o json | jq '.spec.finalizers = []' | kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/$namespace/finalize" -f -
```

Comment: Works for me.  Some explanation would be nice tho.

Answer (score 2):

This article brought me here for a second time, but this time we are using **Rancher (RKE2) Kubernetes edition**.

The trick here is to call directly rancher api in order to pass deletion request... ( trick with proxy does not work). Hope this help someone

**Don't forget to change the Bearer Token**

```
export NS='delete-me';
export YOURFQDN='rancher2.dev.prod.local';
export YOURCLUSTER='c-xxxx1';

kubectl get ns ${NS} -o json | jq '.spec.finalizers=[]' | \
curl -X PUT https://${YOURFQDN}/k8s/clusters/${YOURCLUSTER}/api/v1/namespaces/${NS}/finalize \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer token-xxxx:xxxxYOURxxxxTOKENxxxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @-
```

Comment: Just a footnote to this: I tried to delete a stuck namespace on my RKE2 worker cluster by "k replace --raw ..." and got this error.  `Error from server (Conflict): Operation cannot be fulfilled on namespaces "MY-TERMINATING-NS": StorageError: invalid object, Code: 4, Key: /registry/namespaces/MY-TERMINATING-NS, ResourceVersion: 0, AdditionalErrorMsg: Precondition failed: UID in precondition: 97ff9db3-4e74-45de-b6da-7f8305b8f9f7, UID in object meta:`   Using the above worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in a rke2/Harvester cluster. I tried everything (curl the k8s API, forced delete etc.)

There where no resource left in the namespace.

Lastly i removed the key from etcd:

```bash
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl \
  --cert=/var/lib/rancher/rke2/server/tls/etcd/client.crt \
  --key=/var/lib/rancher/rke2/server/tls/etcd/client.key \
  --cacert=/var/lib/rancher/rke2/server/tls/etcd/server-ca.crt \
  del /registry/namespaces/<NAMESPACE_TO_DELETE>
```

Certainly not the best method to solve the issue. But may be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not able to run the command and are getting any parsing error:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @tmp.json http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/[your-namespace]/finalize
```

Then make sure that the json that you have is having correct finalize like below, note that finalize have **[]** :

```
"spec": {
"finalizers":[
]
```

Answer (score 0):

*I just did below 2 steps and it worked like a charm. Before this, I had tried many ways which all gone in vain.*

**Step-1**

In 1st terminal run `kubectl proxy`

**Step-2**

In 2nd terminal run below command, make sure you have *jq* installed in the system. Just replace *istio-system* by your namespace which you wish to delete and in *Terminating* state.

```
kubectl get ns istio-system -o json | \


 jq '.spec.finalizers=[]' | \



curl -X PUT http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/finalize -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @-
```