# How do I terminate a Kubernetes namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

I am trying to terminate the namespace argo in Kubernetes. In the past, I have succesfully followed the directions found here [Kubernetes Namespaces stuck in Terminating status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954174/kubernetes-namespaces-stuck-in-terminating-status)

this time, however, I am getting the following error message. What does it mean and how can I work around this?

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "namespaces \"argo\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot update resource \"namespaces/finalize\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"argo\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "argo",
    "kind": "namespaces"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an authenticated user that has permissions for the subresource (or more often, for `*`).

Comment: Follow-up question. I only have two users - both authenticated by key. Neither one is able to successfully execute the terminate command. How did I install argo in the first place and how do I terminate in this situation?

Comment: If you've ever tinkered with Argo Workflows, you might have used `kubectl create ns argo` from their documentation.

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw  have been working with Argo Workflows for a while and am learning how to properly secure my system. I suspect this is the reason for my current problem - Argo stopped responding.  I want to reinstall it, but the namespace will not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an authenticated user, such as kubuctl's user

```
cat /root/.kube/config |grep client-certificate-data | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' |base64 -d > ./kubectl.crt
cat /root/.kube/config |grep client-key-data | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' |base64 -d > ./kubectl.key
curl --cert ./kubectl.crt --key ./kubectl.key -k ...
```